# Sinalizar recebimento de mensagens

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, android-notification

Quando eu recebo 1 ou mais mensagens, por exemplo, no What's App, vamos dizer que recebi 3 mensagens. Em cima do ícone do what's app, fica uma "bolinha" alaranjada com o número 3, em realidade a quantidade de chamada. No Linked In a mesma coisa e assim vai para todo aplicativo. Estou fazendo uma App, onde o cliente também vai receber chamada por esse Aplicativo. Como eu faço isso, ou seja, como eu sinalizo indicando a quantidade de mensagens recebidas? Existe algum plugin, dll ou coisa semelhante que eu tenho que carregar em meu App? Fico no aguardo de alguma informação.